# Notify class library from Sql Server after data changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

please consider this scenario:

I have an ASP.Net project with 3 layers architecture. I have a class library for Business logic layer.I store some much needed base information like `Currency Codes` and `Years` in my base information tables and in Application start I get them and store them in an `Application` variable and in `BL` I get them like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Application["CurrencyCodes"]
```

I did this because I did not want to fetch this base info data from data base for every form load.

Now I want update `Application` variable when a currency code added to my base information table automatically.

How I can do this? Can any one show me a sample?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at using [Detecting Changes with SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> A SqlDependency object can be associated with a SqlCommand in order to
>   detect when query results differ from those originally retrieved. You
>   can also assign a delegate to the OnChange event, which will fire when
>   the results change for an associated command. You must associate the
>   SqlDependency with the command before you execute the command. The
>   HasChanges property of the SqlDependency can also be used to determine
>   if the query results have changed since the data was first retrieved.

Possibly also have a look at [SqlDependency in an ASP.NET Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dz445ks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Please take note that you need [Enabling Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172133%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)